# Recursively rename subdirectories that match a regex

Tags: shell, directory, regular-expression, rename

I have a media server with a folder called `Series`. (`/media/Expansion2/Series/`)

In it, I have (surprise!) TV series.  These are just the show names, e.g., `/media/Expansion2/Series/The Big Bang Theory/`

Inside each show's folder (and this is where the problem lies) I have season folders.  I currently have a mixture of the following 2 conventions (along with a few more, probably):

1. `/media/Expansion2/Series/The Big Bang Theory/The Big Bang Theory Season 1`
2. `/media/Expansion2/Series/The Big Bang Theory/Season 2`

In the end, I want to rename all folders to just `Season #`.

As a regex, I would probably say something like `s/.*(Season \d)/$1`

Only applicable to folders, not files.  I should probably also mention that this is for about 50+ show sub folders, so it needs to start at the `/media/Expansion2/Series/` level and look into each series :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu):

```
find /media/Expansion2/Series/ -type d -exec rename -n 's/.*(Season \d)/$1/' {} ";"
```

The `rename` command is part of the Perl package. It is not provided by other distributions, they instead provide the standard Linux `rename` command which is not useful here.

If `rename -n` (-not really) displays what it wants to do, and it's all right for you, omit the -n and make it happen.

Comment: Must say, I've found this method particularly useful over the last few days - not only for folders, but files as well.  Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember, the tool is called `rename` on Debian __only__. On Ubuntu (& some flavors), in order to avoid name clashes with the previously mentioned standard `rename` command, it is sometimes (but not always) found under `prename`. Here on Lubuntu, the tool itself is called `prename` but it may be called as `rename` due to the symlink chain `/usr/bin/rename -> /etc/alternatives/rename -> /usr/bin/file-rename`, where `file-rename` is a slightly modified version of `prename`.

Comment: awesome! That made me do that for multiple files in multiple directories!

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet strips anything that occurs before the last occurrence of `Season [0-9]` in every show directory under `/media/Expansion2/Series`.  No regular expressions necessary, just globs.

```
cd /media/Expansion2/Series
for show in ./*/; do
    (
        cd "$show" || { echo "cd failed.  Skipping $show"; exit 1; }
        for season in ./*Season\ [[:digit:]]*/; do
                season_prefix=${season%Season [[:digit:]]*}
                mv "$season" ./"${season#$season_prefix}"
        done
    )
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to play it safe and only rename `some show/some show stuff` to `some show/stuff`:

```
for d in */; do
  for f in "$d${d%/} *"; do
    mv "$f" "${d}${f%$d${d%/} }"
  done
done
```

If you want to strip everything before `Season`:

```
for x in */*Season*; do
  mv "$x" "${x%/*}/${x##*Season}Season"
done
```

`${var#PATTERN}` strips PATTERN at the beginning of `$var` and returns the result. `${var%PATTERN}` does the same at the end. `${var#PATTERN}` and `${var%PATTERN}` remove the shortest matching prefix and suffix respectively; `${var##PATTERN}` and `${var%%PATTERN}` remove the longest match.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post two more solutions in the hope that they may be helpful in future.  These came from the Linux admins at work.  Just goes to show how many hammers will work on this nail!

#### Solution 1:

> Hi Denham,
>
> I'm having to make a few assumptions here, for instance that the part of the directory with "XXX Season #" will always be the "outside" directory (leaf node).
>
> In any case, I would write a little script. Something like this should work (note the double quotes around the variables, to ensure you capture all the spaces in the directories):
>
> ```
> find /media/Expansion2/Series/ -type d | while read olddir
> do 
>    newdir=`echo "${olddir}" | awk -F "/" '$NF ~ /Season/ { last=substr($NF,index($NF, "Season")); while (i<(NF-1)) { i++; printf("/%s", $i) }; printf("/%s\n", last) } $NF !~ /Season/ { print }'`
>    if [ "${olddir}" != "${newdir}" ]
>    then
>        mv "${olddir}" "${newdir}"
>    fi
> done
> ```
>
> Of course, before you run it with the command " mv "${olddir}" "${newdir}" " you should put something like " echo "${olddir}" "${newdir}" " to ensure you're getting the results you expect or you could end up with another headache :-P

#### Solution 2:

> Hi Denham,
>
> Most of the answer was already in the question. Anyway running something like the following from the Series folder should work just fine:
>
> ```
> find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d | while read dir; do mv -T "$dir" "`dirname "$dir"`/`basename "$dir" | sed "s/.*Season \([0-9]*\)$/Season \1/i"`"; done
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>   • find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d (list directories two levels down)
>   • while read dir; (loop on each dir)
>   • mv -T "$dir" (move the source dir to... -T is needed to get an error if the Season folders are not unique i.e. you don't have "The Big Bang Theory Season 22" and "Season 22" in the same directory)
>   • dirname "$dir"  returns the path where the dir is
>   • basename "$dir" returns the name of the directory
>   • sed "s/.*Season ([0-9]*)$/Season \1/i" completes the magic with case insensitive regexp, just in case.
>
> In my small test it worked (try it first with an echo before mv):
>
> `someuser@linux-box:/tmp/Series$ find
>
>   .
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file1.avi
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file 3.avi
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file2.avi
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/3.avi
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/The Big Bang Theory Season 1
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/The Big Bang Theory Season 1/file1.avi
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/The Big Bang Theory Season 1/file 3.avi
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/The Big Bang Theory Season 1/file2.avi
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/The Big Bang Theory Season 1/file
>
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/The Big Bang Theory Season 1/3.avi
>
>   ./Other Series
>
>   ./Other Series/Season 2
>
>   ./Other Series/Stre dsfdf sd dSeason 3`
>
> someuser@linux-box:/tmp/Series$ find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d | while read dir; do mv -T "$dir" "`dirname "$dir"`/`basename "$dir" | sed "s/.*Season \([0-9]*\)$/Season \1/i"`"; done
>   mv: `./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2' and`./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2' are the same file  
>   mv: `./Other Series/Season 2' and`./Other Series/Season 2' are the same file
>
> someuser@linux-box:/tmp/Series$ find
>   .
>   ./The Big Bang Theory
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file1.avi
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file 3.avi
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file2.avi
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/file
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 2/3.avi
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 1
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 1/file1.avi
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 1/file 3.avi
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 1/file2.avi
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 1/file
>   ./The Big Bang Theory/Season 1/3.avi
>   ./Other Series
>   ./Other Series/Season 3
>   ./Other Series/Season 2